# MySql command line: execute two queries at once?

Tags: mysql, join, command-line

I am using the MySql command tool to query a database from inside a Ruby script I wrote. However the need has arisen for a query that creates a temporary table, then in another query I need to perform a join on the temporary table. The only problem is every time I invoke `mysql -h <host> -r <username> -D <database> -e "QUERY"` I get a new transaction, so when I am trying to perform my join, the temporary table doesn't exist anymore.

Is there anyway to do execute two separate queries in **one** invocation of the mysql command line tool??

Something like:
`mysql -h <host> -r <username> -D <database> -e "QUERY1" -e "QUERY2"`

Or is there some alternative way to store my queries? like in a text file or something?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried seperating them with a semi-colon?

Comment: You could execute a script file - shell> mysql <params> <file.sql>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wouldn't the ";" do the trick?

`mysql -h <host> -r <username> -D <database> -e "QUERY1;QUERY2"`

Comment: This worked great! Thanks. I read through the documentation for the command line tool and didn't see ';' marked as a separator.

Comment: It was a lucky guess ;). Also if you are about to query the temporary table multiple times and you care about performance, it might be better to create a connection to the mysql. Then you can create the table just once and execute all the queries in one session.

Comment: I just need it for a single small query, and I had to create a temp table because it isn't my database :( Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: it stopped working!